# Should I mention an honorary role that included very limited responsibilities?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I currently work for a small company. A couple of years ago, our CEO set up a sister company, and several of us did odd-jobs to assist in getting it up and running.

At one point, he was concerned that if anyone looked the company up on LinkedIn and saw that it had no official employees, that they'd think it was a one-man-band and be wary of dealing with him. So, he assigned everyone in the main company a job role in the sister company and asked us to update employment profiles on LinkedIn. This was so that anyone viewing the sister company would see that it had several people employed.

While I did work for the company and contribute to its growth, it was mainly advisory work on a very sporadic basis. Certainly nothing even approaching the work that would have come with the title I was given.

It seemed harmless at the time, but now I'm looking for other work and I'm unsure how to handle it.

Should I simply remove the sister company from my social network profiles and never mention it? Could this eventually come back to haunt me in some way?

Alternatively, as I could (tenuously) argue that I worked for the company, is it worth including on social profiles or my CV as another feather in my cap?

Comment: I could imagine that *listing* this "make-believe" job at a "make-believe" company (no offense meant) could come back to haunt you at least as much as *not listing* it. Looking forward to the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your role as a token in the sister company was not your doing but your boss's. Leave the sister company in your network profile. Don't mention the sister company and your role in it at interviews.

If an interviewer asks about what you did there, say what you just said in your post: advisory work on a sporadic basis and the whole concept was your boss's idea for generating a few extra bucks - That's it.

Then get back to focusing on what you did or are doing for the main company.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend NOT listing this role.

Your resume is supposed to be your means of advertising what you have to offer to potential employers.

The thing is the job was only kind of a job, you mention advising from time to time, however; if you put this on your resume a good interviewer will likely sniff it out. If you're up front and say this was a sister company that you have only a few dealings with it would seem shady or leave them wondering why you put it on your resume, surely you had something more worth mentioning.

It's doubtful anyone will ask, their won't be an employment gap or anything. (I've never had a recruiter ask me about what I had on LinkedIn, they've always asked for a resume)

IF someone asks just tell it like it is. Your boss had you assist with his sister company so while you technically worked at both places in reality you barely worked at the sister company past advisement so felt listing it wouldn't be appropriate.

If I was interviewing you, it'd probably be mildly interesting, but neutral in regards to my view of your past employment.